# How does mapPartitions behave in a loop?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to understand, how does mapPartitions function behave in the following code. Does it create separate partitions in each iteration and assigns them to the nodes. Or The partitions and the mappings of partitions to nodes is preserved across iterations?

Ideally I would like to keep the same partitioning for the whole loop.

```
for i in range(10):
    x = rdd.mapPartitions(fun).reduce(lambda a,b:a+b)
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If `rdd` is cached then partitions will be computed once and preserved across iterations unless there is some kind of failure and task is rescheduled on another worker. Otherwise it will be recomputed for each iteration. In such a case the answer depends on a lineage of the `rdd`. If there is no shuffling involved or you use deterministic partitioning and ordering then the answer is positive. Otherwise it is unlikely you'll see the same content in each iteration.

If you are concerned about performance then caching will be enough. If you think about performing some side effects inside `mapPartitions` and you want these to be preserved between iterations then you cannot depend on that.

Comment: This is a good description of how caching works in spark RDD's.